# Since updating to Big Sur Mail.app search *of any kind* is not working

Tags: macos, mail.app, upgrade, search, big-sur

I simply do not get the "All Mailboxes" mailbox icon in the mailbox panel of OSX.

I followed the directions here:

https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/fixing-broken-mail-search-macos/

So I restarted Spotlight indexing, then deleted the Mail envelope files in accordance with the advice on macobserver.

This caused a rebuild of Mail data with a long progress bar and restored functionality but only *temporarily.*

After some time, generally after closing and reopening the clamshell on my MBP, Mail search fails again and requires a logout/login to fix. Search from Spotlight fails as well as from within Mail.

I have Siri off, and has always been. I can't imagine what else could affect specifically Mail search when search works in other contexts, and worked previously.

This problem affects a 2015 MBP and an older Mac Mini that fails after some time sleeping. Logout/login restores functionality here as well, but only temporarily.